# Laravel Scheduler

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-scheduler

I'm new to Laravel Scheduler. Whenever I add something to my database (let's say entry A), I schedule an event (which will trigger after some time).

What I can't figure out is: if I delete entry A, and its event has not been triggered, is there any way to see (before the scheduled task runs for entry A)  whether entry A exists in the database or not?

Comment: Why not have the event check that for itself?

Comment: @litelite I wasn't able to get what you are saying. Can you please explain a little bit.

and wouldn't it be great that when that record is being deleted that scheduled event(If it has yet to be triggered) should also be deleted rather than when it triggers and then we check that if it exists or not. 

If there is a way to do this wouldn't that be awesome